# Joomla mulitple layouts in a single template?

Tags: joomla

Respected Specialists,

Is it possilble to create mulitple layouts inside a single joomla template ?. So that for each menu we can choose different layouts from the same template ?

Yours faithfully

Murulimadhav

Comment: Yes, you give them different names, this was a change from Joomla 1.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can.  You can code it by hand yourself if you want to, or look at using a library like [Gantry](http://www.gantry-framework.org/documentation/joomla/basics/installation.md) to do the job.

Gantry is reasonably easy - as it gives you some default templates to start with.  You can then customize them, and nominate which positions within the template actually display.

Comment: Respected Sir, thanks  lot, Gantry is doing that work with framework installed.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to make multiple copies of your template, modify them and assign them to the various menus. To duplicate a template follow the steps described in the following:

- [Joomla2.5](http://www.templatemonster.com/help/joomla-how-to-duplicate-and-assign-template-to-some-page.html)
- [Joomla3.2](http://docs.joomla.org/J3.2%3aModifying_a_Joomla!_Template)

Comment: Respected Sir, ya that i know, but by that method, for each page whole css file, logo, css images will be newly loaded, which may make the websie slower. yours faithfully